# How to disable specific shipping method based on product's attribute value from checkout process

Tags: netsuite

From, order_wizard_shipmethod_module.tpl

I found this,

```
               {{#each shippingMethods}}
                    <a data-action="select-delivery-option-radio" 
                    class="order-wizard-shipmethod-module-option {{#if isActive}}order-wizard-shipmethod-module-option-active{{/if}}"
                    data-value="{{internalid}}">
                        <input type="radio" name="delivery-options" data-action="edit-module" class="order-wizard-shipmethod-module-checkbox" 
                        {{#if isActive}}checked{{/if}}
                        value="{{internalid}}" 
                        id="delivery-options-{{internalid}}" />

                        <span class="order-wizard-shipmethod-module-option-name">{{name}}
                            <span class="order-wizard-shipmethod-module-option-price">{{rate_formatted}}</span> 
                        </span>
                    </a>
                {{/each}}
```

I'm wondering how can I get product's attribute value within shopping cart and disable specific shipping method?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the attribute values of each shipping method, then go to the Javascript file `OrderWizard.Module.CartSummary.js` and in the `getContext` function, after the confirmation variable is defined, put in `console.log(summary);`.

In your Cart, look in the console and within attributes is shipmethod and you'll find what you need in there.